# AngularJS where to put all script tags location

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS.
Where do I place all .js files like module,routes and controllers?

I found examples but they put all of it inside of  tags.

like I currently code like this:

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.routes.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/home/homeController.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/skills/skillsController.js"></script>
</html>
```

Is this normal? Or is there a proper way to include the files?

I have heard of RequireJS. But there a way without using it?

Thank you very much.

Regards,

Yuri

Comment: The proper way would indeed be to use a webpack tool.

Comment: Why not using RequireJS?

Answer (score 0):

You can include files normally before end body tag `</body>` - it's ok.

But more efficient way is pack your files into one or few groups (Libraries, Core, Modules) and minify. It is better to have fewer HTTP requests, so you should reduce amount of files.

To bundle your files and minify you can use gulp or webpack:

See example with gulp:
https://github.com/jhades/angularjs-gulp-example

See example with webpack:
https://github.com/zombiQWERTY/angular-webpack-starter

Answer (score 0):

There is no right answer.

There are multiple ways. One of them being using `<script>` tags as your code does.
Other options are:

- Gulp
- Gulp + Bower
- Webpack
- RequireJS
- SystemJS

You can also use Yeoman to scaffold your project with build pipeline in place.

Answer (score 0):

Few tips, you should pick and choose which ones are applicable to your app.

1. After all your application markup, load your scripts.
2. You may use a bundler, here is a starter project I created some time ago [gulp-browserify-starter](https://github.com/rahulballal/gulper). #1 still applies.
3. Go through a bit more pain and use webpack to bundle your vendor and app code as distinct bundles.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all your javascript just before body close tag instead of head

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
.......
.......
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.routes.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/home/homeController.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/skills/skillsController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```